Possible to remove revisioning from an entity type entirely?
We implemented a custom entity type a few years back with revisioning enabled, either thinking that it would be useful or not realizing it was enabled. As it turns out, we've never actually used revisioning, so we now have useless revision-related tables for the entities and their fields sitting in the database. These entities are generated en masse, with over 1 million of them currently present, meaning these useless tables are taking up multiple GB of space in the database.
Since we never actually used revisions, there is really only the one "latest" revision present for any entity, so deleting excess revisions is not useful in our case.
Is there a practical way to remove revisioning entirely, or are we stuck? Can't seem to find any information on this.

Last time I went on a crusade to check the same thing (about a year ago), the answer was “no”, because the field storage is completely tied to the concept of revisions. Revisions can be enabled/disabled easily, and it would potentially be a lot of upheaval to create/delete tables, copy data, etc., on the fly any time that happens. So a database structure was created that could support both states easily, and the potential data duplication is the unavoidable side-effect. That’s my understanding anyway

You can create a simple entity type stored in one database table and one table row per entity. The problem though seems to be there is an update API to upgrade entity types but not to downgrade. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3024727. If this is a custom entity installed on one site I would export the data, uninstall the module with the complex entity type, install the module with the simple entity type and reimport the data. If this is for a contributed module you need an update hook which might be difficult without API support.

Thanks y'all for the insights. Those were both the impressions that I got but just wanted to make sure. Somewhat of a pain but understandable.
